# Is this a Fallacy: "Never let your sense of morals prevent you from doing what is right"?

Tags: quotes

This is in my quote collection and said by some *Salvor Hardin*. I forgot when and why I had added it to the collection, but now that I was randomly going through it, this quote has just stumped me.

I think this statement is totally conflicting and a logical fallacy in itself. How can you stop your sense of morals from preventing you from doing what is right, when the moral sense itself determines what is right and wrong? To be more clear, it is our sense of morality that determines what is right and wrong. So, its like saying "jump from this table, and at the same time don't jump". Am I not understanding something?

Comment: This might help [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salvor_Hardin).  Hardin is a fictional character in a story by Isaac Asimov, who faces a moral dilemma.

Comment: It is not a *tautology*, for that would be *He had high moral standards and always did right*. But somehow it seems to stand in a relationship to tautology, though it is not the antonym of one. So what the devil is it?

Comment: The SE site to ask about logical fallacies is [Philosophy.se], though before you go ask there, you might want to try to frame the question more academically. Here, the question has to be closed, because it's about the *content* of an utterance, not the *form*.

Comment: It means that your moral code could be wrong.

Comment: @deadrat Indeed. If the person concerned was adjudged to have a perverse moral outlook, then the statement would make perfect sense.

Comment: [Huckleberry Finn](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/76/76-h/76-h.htm) provides an example: he continues to believe the perverse moral code that he has been taught, by which liberating a slave is a mortal sin, even as he opts to do precisely that anyway, instinctively following a moral code we would surely agree is a higher one. He says, "All right, then, I'll *go* to hell" (Chap. 31).

Comment: As WS2 states, "If the person concerned was adjudged ...'. But _who_ is qualified to make this judgement? The Christian religion believes in absolute right and wrong; also, however, that fallen man is unable to judge correctly (and wouldn't want to). Conscience is vital (otherwise man is merely an animal), but also not properly aligned with correct moral decisions. One can do what one feels to be right and still be wrong. Thus “Never let your sense of morals prevent you from doing what is right” would make sense. But who can follow this advice?

Comment: I am not familiar with the author, but I think it could be one of two things (or both) 1) The statement is exemplifying irony, or 2)  Like @Deadrat said, but I think that statement could be more generalized to mean that despite what you were taught, don't let your instincts fall by the wayside.  It doesn't have to apply strictly to morals.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about a specific dilemma facing a fictional character (in Foundation, by Isaac Asimov.)  If the Question is still open in a few days, I will have reread the book and will answer.

Comment: This is a question about ethics and philosophy, not English.  (But it is neither tautology nor oxymoron.)

Comment: (But consider that many people would consider "honor killing" to be the "moral" thing to do.)

Comment: (If this question were to be somehow on-topic it would possibly be by asking what rhetorical device is it that presents an apparent oxymoron/contradiction but which is not a contradiction upon full consideration and comprehension.  This is not just a relatively common rhetorical device but also, in real life, at the core of many of society's ills.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A conflict of two or more moral principles often arises. The Ten Commandments say *thou shalt not kill*, but some Christians think that capital punishment is alright. A Greek chap called Plato deals with issues rather like this in his book *The Republic*. What is justice? Is it what we (through Parliament) and the law say is justice? Or is justice an absolute principle, irrespective of what the law says?

Comment: The Ten Commandments were originally given in Hebrew; 'Thou shalt not kill' is a poor translation (see [ApologeticsPress](https://www.apologeticspress.org/apcontent.aspx?category=6&article=1415) that almost all versions of the Bible have replaced nowadays. // The original sin has been interpreted as man trying to usurp God's right to be the final arbiter of right and wrong (which right God would, I'm sure, readily have shared were man able to handle it).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My maths was never good enough for theology!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fallacy is an error in reasoning that renders an argument false. It is also used to describe a mistaken belief. The quoted saying is not a fallacy.

Asimov's characters in the Foundation novels describe the quoted saying as an "epigram": a pithy saying or remark expressing an idea in a clever and amusing way. In this case the idea being expressed is that ones "sense of morals" can be an unreliable guide to the right action, and that sometimes an action that appears immoral on the surface can actually be the most moral course of action when properly understood.

There is an area where psychology and moral philosophy overlap called "trollyology" after its paradigmatic example, in which you are asked to choose between diverting a runaway rail trolly so that it will kill one person, or doing nothing and watching several people be killed. Researchers in this area are concerned with understanding situations where someone's sense of morals would prevent them from doing the right thing. For instance, most people are willing to pull a lever to divert the trolly onto a line with one victim, but not to actually push the victim under the trolly with their own hands.

Comment: As I recall the underlying situation, the mission of the First Foundation  was to reduce the inevitable dark ages that would succeed the falling of the Empire from 30,000 years to 1,000 years. (This was on a galactic scale.)  So plus 1, especially for your second paragraph.